# How to avoid redundancy while writing REST resources in Kotlin?

Tags: hibernate, rest, kotlin, resteasy, quarkus

I'm working on a backend application in Kotlin/Quarkus. Now I'm creating REST resources, but I have quite a lot of endpoints for which I need to create resources. I'd like to avoid copy/pasting a lot of identical code.

What are ways to avoid this?

I've already tried to create a GenericResource class, which can then be inherited by my UserResource for example. This doesn't seem to work however, referring to the following link: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3632

What are other ways to avoid this redundancy of code?

Comment: Have you tried https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache?

Comment: Looks good! Trying it out right now.